# what does に do in いつの間にこんな自立した子に…

Tags: particles, particle-に, anime

I don't understand why に is used in this sentence I saw this sentence in the second episode of the anime k-on

> いつの間にこんな自立した子**に**...うれしいような悲しいような

the English subs said that it meant

> She's all independent already.It makes me both happy and sad

Comment: Which に? If you are talking about the 自立した子に part, なる implicitly follow.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, this is a case of omission. In Japanese, if the intent of the statement is free of ambiguity, you can cut out the rest.

> いつの間に【この子は】こんな【に】自立した子に【なったのだろう 】。【私は】うれしいような悲しいような【気持ちです】。